# Story from the Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction about a "lateral transfer"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A man is being downgraded by his anonymous employers and "transferred laterally" in his office: walls are moving and changing, the interior is changing. When he comes home to his wife, a different woman is waiting for him...

Comment: Hi Klaus, welcome to SciFi & Fantasy! Can you please go through [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if you can add any more info? When did you read this, what language was it in, can you remember how anything looked, what time was it set in, &c.?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 15):

"[Kite: Yellow and Green](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50596)" (1973) by Robert Lory seems to fit.  It's a very short story (5 pages) and was published only in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, January 1973.

The story ends:

> Duluth Central did not have Topeka’s winning sense of humor, I reflected, as I stood before the door of my new apartment. Thirteen, and he'd let it pass without comment.
>
> I rang the bell. The door opened. I smiled. The family was waiting.
>
> The kid. "Did you bring the kite. Daddy? Yellow and green?"
>
> My smile began to fade.
>
> Her. "Hi. Sorry about the kid. His last father promised."
>
> I had no trace of a smile now. True, the ten-year-old this time was a boy. True, the wife had a lighter shade of hair. But still small boobs.
>
> **It was a lateral transfer**.

It's hard to quote the part that shows the office reconfiguring itself; it's nearly half of the story so I'll just quote a portion:

> Anyway, the window wall was second. A steel panel slid over the front of the glass.
>
> *Whir*. And a slight rumble-rumble. This was at my feet as the floor prepared to move up or down or vertically, whichever was its—and my—destination.
>
> We moved southeast, the floor moving out at about twenty KPH. *Whir*. And I noticed something I didn’t like much. Of course, I never liked it much. The way the walls seem to close in on you.

You can read the entire story at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v044n01_1973-01/page/n97/mode/2up).

Comment: thank you David, this is exactly the story. I read it in a German anthology "Aufstand der Kryonauten" (Heyne), have just ordered the book.
Klaus